how to save object in an object?

I want to save user as object in rating object, but when I am going to add it its userId adding instead of whole user object ?


const reviewSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "name is require"],
    },
    rating: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0,
    },
    comment: {
      type: String,
    },
    user: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Users",
      required: [true, "user require"],
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

This is the model of rating in which user object added.
   const user = await userModel.findById({ _id: req.user._id });
    console.log(user);
    // review object
    const review = {
      name: user.name,
      rating: Number(rating),
      comment,
      user,
    };

This is the controller function in which user has gotted from request.params._id, but when I am going to save user object only its ID is being saving in database.

When you define a reference to another model in a schema, Mongoose expects the referenced field to store just the ObjectId, not the entire object. This is why only the user ID is being saved in the database.And this what it supposed to do.

kindly mention how to save whole object instead of OBJECTID ?

Just put req.user._id as an argument of findById. Like below:
const user = await userModel.findById(req.user._id);

